# Change description of facebook page in google search result

Tags: facebook-comments

Google search: "*company name* facebook"

Description in search result: (*unhappy customer's comment retrieved from facebook page content, not facebook page meta description*).

Possible to change this Google search result description?

When I say "Description in search result", I mean the text in this image with red arrows pointing at it:
[image]

Google is using a facebook users' comment as the description in their search result for "*company name* facebook".

Comment: Confirmation: you are wanting to change a description for a search result on Google?

Comment: Yes, I believe there are ways to influence what Google chooses to use as the description in some circumstances. I'm wondering if it is possible to do so in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this page: http://support.aarcadethemes.com/how-do-i-update-or-change-the-google-search-results-for-my-site/

```
The description of your search result is generated by an automated Google process
that takes into account both the content of the page, the page description meta
tag in the head of your page code and references to the page that appear on the
web. While the description of your search result is often the same as the page
description meta tag content, this is not always the case and is by no means
guaranteed.
```

The idea here is to change your code between your `<head></head>`.  The most likely candidate for this would probably be the `<title>` tag (as this answer suggests: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100415072702AAfrSVH)

You should also be able to use `<meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description. This will often show up in search results.">` to help change what Google shows.

Your main issue seems to be that Google Search has recently started using comments as potential results: http://losangeles.cbslocal.com/2011/11/03/google-to-index-facebook-comments-as-search-results/

For this, you may find this information informative ([source](http://www.facebook.com/help/392235220834308/)):

```
When people post to an open forum on the site (ex: on Pages, in open groups or
in the Community Forum section of the Help Center) the posts may also appear
in search results from search engines like Yahoo and Google.

Facebook does not have control over content that's already been indexed and
cached by search engines. If you want to remove a piece of content that
you've shared publicly from an internet search engine, you can:

Delete the original post. When you do this, the content may still show up
in search engines, but the link to that content will be invalid.
Contact the specific search engine’s support team. If you want the entire
search result to go away, please reach out to the search engine to remove it.
```

I think your options, then are:

- Try to get the commenter in question to change/remove their comment
- Contact Google: https://support.google.com/websearch/
- Try to alter the header content of the page
- Attempt to get a different comment to become the description

If you could provide the literal string you are searching (in this case the company name) We may be able to help further.  If you have technical issues when implementing a solution, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the well thought out answer and research. I'm sure the person in charge of social media for our company is doing their best to encourage positive comments. I may contact Google if we exhaust other options, thank you for the link. I haven't checked with our social media person for awhile, but the description is actually much better now, and matches the meta description on the Facebook page. I'll report back here if we did anything to change that. Maybe Google changed what they use as the description in the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we made any changes that triggered Google to show a different description, but Google searches for my employer's Facebook page are, happily, now showing the "Mission"
section of the "About" page from our Facebook settings. And that Mission statement is also in the meta description and og:description on our Facebook page.

If anyone else has this problem, try adding a Mission statement under About in your Facebook settings. (There is an actual form text box in the settings, labeled mission. This is not a custom field or some funky keyword matching thing, just an input box in the About section of the Facebook settings.)